el juego de adivinar el número en Pseint
tengo una tarea con Pseint, de un juego de adivinar el número, y tengo una consigna que no puedo resolver, que cuando el usuario escriba un intento, lo almacene en un array, y me los vaya ordenando de manera ascendente, y además que si repito el número, me lo diga, y no lo cuente como intento, por favor no pude resolverlo ni con ayuda de IA.
este es el código que tengo hasta ahora y me funciona bien.
Proceso JuegoAdivinarNumero
Definir rangoMinimo, rangoMaximo, numero, intentosMaximos, intentosRestantes, intento, intentosUsados Como Entero
Escribir "Bienvenido al juego de adivinar el número."
//Ingresando el rango de números para el juego API1
Escribir "Ingrese el rango de números para el juego:"
Escribir "Rango mínimo:"
Leer rangoMinimo
Escribir "Rango máximo:"
Leer rangoMaximo
//Ingresando la cantidad de intentos API1
Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad máxima de intentos:"
Leer intentosMaximos

// Validar los rangos ingresados y la cantidad de intentos API2
Mientras rangoMinimo >= rangoMaximo O intentosMaximos <= 0 Hacer
    Escribir "Error: Por favor ingrese un rango válido y una cantidad de intentos mayor a 0."
    Escribir "Rango mínimo:"
    Leer rangoMinimo
    Escribir "Rango máximo:"
    Leer rangoMaximo
    Escribir "Ingrese la cantidad máxima de intentos:"
    Leer intentosMaximos
FinMientras
// Número aleatorio generado por el programa API1
numero = Aleatorio(rangoMinimo, rangoMaximo)
intentosRestantes = intentosMaximos
intentosUsados = 0

// El programa debe indicar al usuario cuántos intentos lleva y cuántos intentos le quedan API2
Mientras intentosRestantes > 0
    Escribir "Intentos restantes:", intentosRestantes
    Escribir "Intentos usados:", intentosUsados
    // Programa solicita un número al usuario para intentar adivinar API1
    Escribir "Ingrese un número:"
    Leer intento
    
    // Validar si el número ingresado está dentro de los rangos establecidos API2
    Si intento < rangoMinimo O intento > rangoMaximo Entonces
        Escribir "Error: El número ingresado está fuera del rango establecido."
        
    FinSi
    
    Si intento = numero Entonces
        Escribir "¡Felicitaciones! Ha adivinado el número."
        intentosRestantes = 0 // en esta parte intenté poner "Detener", pero no me funciona, busqué en google una función en Pseint que haga eso y no me salió nada, por eso tuve que reducir los intentos a 0
    Sino
        // El programa debe indicar si el número ingresado por el usuario es mayor o menor que el número generado API2
        Si intento < numero Entonces
            Escribir "El número a adivinar es mayor."
        Sino
            Escribir "El número a adivinar es menor."
        FinSi
    FinSi
    
    intentosUsados = intentosUsados + 1
    intentosRestantes = intentosRestantes - 1
FinMientras

Si intentosRestantes <= 0 Entonces
    Escribir "Se acabaron los intentos. El número a adivinar era:", numero
FinSi

FinProceso

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual seria el problema si funciona bien?
